# Catching Mocha Assertion Error with Selenium on Windows

Tags: node.js, testing, selenium, mocha.js

I am trying to run through a simple tutorial on how to use selenium webdriver.  The following code works fine when the test passes but when I have the assert.equal fail I get a urgly error message in my shell.

[image]

```
var assert = require('assert'),
test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing'),
webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

test.describe('Google Search', function() {
  test.it('should work', function() {

    var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();

    driver.get('http://www.yahoo.com');
    var searchBox = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('p'));
    searchBox.sendKeys('simple programmer');

    searchBox.getAttribute('value').then(function(value) {
      assert.equal(value, 'simple programmer');
    });

    driver.quit();  
  });

});
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by completely re installing node.js.  After re installing express installed just fine.

Comment: This was almost certainly a Windows-specific issue. :P

Comment: Honestly I would learn Selenium on Mac OS X or Linux. You'll keep having to reinstall pretty much everything (maybe even the OS) if you keep using Windows.

Comment: I have a mac at home so I am right there with you... But at work I am stuck on windows.  It's not all bad.